# Sending smtp mail without smtp server installed locally

Tags: php, codeigniter

Should I be able to send SMTP email on my local development PC with CodeIgniter without having a SMTP server application installed on my local development PC?

For example, the following doesn't work.

application/config/email.php

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'my_gmail_account@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '*********';
```

controller code

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('my_gmail_account@gmail.com', 'Noel');
$this->email->to('my_gmail_account@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('SMTP email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing smtp email in codeigniter.');
$this->email->send();

$data['message'] = "Sorry Unable to send email...";
if($this->email->send()){
  $data['message'] = "Mail sent...";
}

$this->load->view('test_view', $data);
```

The following returns

> Sorry Unable to send email...

and doesn't arrive at the destination email.

Comment: Have you checked through the GMail SMTP troubleshooting guide? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: @gabe3886 - Hi, I noticed that link was the IMAP POP guide. Are the sections like "Have you enabled POP or IMAP in Gmail?" then required for sending mail with SMTP?

Comment: Also from the problems guide, I am able to access gmail with telnet smtp.gmail.com on ports 465, 587, but not 25. Since I'm using ssl and 465, I guess this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading parameters into an array and then initializing the library using array [source: CodeIgniter Forum](http://web.archive.org/web/20091027211607/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/132443/):

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

Also, maybe you need to enable SSL in your `php.ini`. If you see the line:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

uncomment it by removing semicolon from the beginning of the line and then restart PHP.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick (kind of), but not for the reason you gave. There are two reasons why my code didn't work, and one reason why yours didn't (for me at least). 
1. When using google for smtp delivery, go here https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and select "Turn on" to allow access for less secure apps (source: http://www.wpsitecare.com/gmail-smtp-settings/ ). 
2. $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); needs to be added after the library call. 

I'm happy to give you the accepted answer because in a way it does feature an essential requirement.